# GNU sed regex to fix mySQL db inserts for SQLite

Tags: regex, sed, gnu

I am trying to translate a huge mySQL database dump file from mySQL syntax into SQLite syntax.

At https://regex101.com/ I have successfully created a ECMAScript flavor regex to turn something like:

```
,'foo\'s bar!',
```

into:

```
,"foo\'s bar!"
```

with this regular expression:

```
/,'([^']+)\\'([^']+)',/"$1\\'$2"/g
```

testing against this short file:

```
(1058,'gpl5q0x51349lmdq3e0ijm4k9b6n','Henry\'s_1.csv','text/csv','{\"identified\":true,\"analyzed\":true}',33854,'mUVk0/XGX+afIpkrqBm7LQ==','2021-01-06 03:07:23'),
(1059,'xzj8mivsenkakkrurfjytxjsaj1h','Henry\'s_2.csv','text/csv','{\"identified\":true,\"analyzed\":true}',33555,'KfRYqfAWtSIYXZ6oQZyYbA==','2021-01-06 03:07:23'),
```

Resulting in:

```
(1058,'gpl5q0x51349lmdq3e0ijm4k9b6n'"Henry\'s_1.csv"'text/csv','{\"identified\":true,\"analyzed\":true}',33854,'mUVk0/XGX+afIpkrqBm7LQ==','2021-01-06 03:07:23'),
(1059,'xzj8mivsenkakkrurfjytxjsaj1h'"Henry\'s_2.csv"'text/csv','{\"identified\":true,\"analyzed\":true}',33555,'KfRYqfAWtSIYXZ6oQZyYbA==','2021-01-06 03:07:23'),
```

but for the life of me I cannot translate this into a GNU sed flavor regex.
For example, this command does not make any substitutions in the output:

```
sed -r s/,'([^']+)\\'([^']+)',/"$1\\'$2"/g <test.sql
...
sed -r s/,'([^']+)\\'([^']+)',/"\1\\'\2"/g <test.sql: doesn't work either.
```

I have looked for a regex tool online that translates between different flavors of regex but cannot find one that works on GNU sed (shipped with GIT: sed (GNU sed) 4.8).  PCRE seems to be close to what sed has but that doesn't work.  I tried perl as well, no luck.
Anyone know a regex expression that works or a translator tool that works?
I am just about ready to write a nodejs program to do this for me.

Also, for extra credit, how can I write a sed script to handle any number of escaped quotes within a quoted string?  I have that issue to deal with as well in my DB dump file.

Examples:

```
'foo\'-bar'  // on instance
'foo\'and\'bar'  // two instances
'foo\'and\'bar\'s on the deck'  // three instances
and so on...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want `,"foo\'s bar!"` or `,"foo\'s bar!",`? Without the comma the result doesn't make sence.

Comment: Is the question solved or do you need more assistance? Please consider updating the question if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
sed -E "s/,'([^']+)\\\\'([^']+)',/"'"'"\\1\\\\'\\2"'"'/g test.sql
```

The `"s/,'([^']+)\\\\'([^']+)',/"'"'"\\1\\\\'\\2"'"'/g` consists of

- `"s/,'([^']+)\\\\'([^']+)',/"` - a `s/,'([^']+)\\'([^']+)',/` part (inside double quotes, so backslashes need doubling)
- `'"'` - a `"` char (inside single quotes)
- `"\\1\\\\'\\2"` - `\1\\'\2` pattern (inside double quotes, so backslashes are doubled)
- `'"'` - a `"` char (inside single quotes)
- `/g` - the global flag (no need quoting here).

Answer (score 0):

First look at your command

```
sed -r s/,'([^']+)\\'([^']+)',/"\1\\'\2"/g test.sql
```

I prefer writing the whole `sed` command in single quotes. When you need a single quote, you must close the string (`'`), use an escaped single quote (`\'`) and open the next string with a `'`, all joined: `'\''`.
I also added two `,` characters.

```
sed -r 's/,'\''([^'\'']+)\\'\''([^'\'']+)'\'',/,"\1\\'\''\2",/g' test.sql
# Shorter
sed -r 's/,'\''([^'\'']+\\'\''[^'\'']+)'\'',/,"\1",/g' test.sql
# Using another way to write the single quotes, with the hex notation
sed -r 's/,\x27([^\x27]+\\\x27[^\x27]+)\x27,/,"\1",/g' test.sql
```

This works for simple cases, not for `'foo\'and\'bar\'s on the deck'`.

I think you want to replace the quotes in the simple fields too.
Suppose you want to transform

```
(1058,'gpl5q0x51349lmdq3e0ijm4k9b6n','Henry\'s_1.csv','text/csv','{\"identified\":true,\"analyzed\":true}',33854,'mUVk0/XGX+afIpkrqBm7LQ==','2021-01-06 03:07:23'),
(1059,'xzj8mivsenkakkrurfjytxjsaj1h','Henry\'s_2.csv','text/csv','{\"identified\":true,\"analyzed\":true}',33555,'KfRYqfAWtSIYXZ6oQZyYbA==','2021-01-06 03:07:23'),
(2000,'extra credit from question','foo\'and\'bar\'s on the deck','text/csv','{\"identified\":true,\"analyzed\":true}',33999,'KgSBFstbdthdsssssstvbA==','2022-01-02 13:07:23'),
```

into

```
(1058,"gpl5q0x51349lmdq3e0ijm4k9b6n","Henry\'s_1.csv","text/csv","{\"identified\":true,\"analyzed\":true}",33854,"mUVk0/XGX+afIpkrqBm7LQ==","2021-01-06 03:07:23"),
(1059,"xzj8mivsenkakkrurfjytxjsaj1h","Henry\'s_2.csv","text/csv","{\"identified\":true,\"analyzed\":true}",33555,"KfRYqfAWtSIYXZ6oQZyYbA==","2021-01-06 03:07:23"),
(2000,"extra credit from question","foo\'and\'bar\'s on the deck","text/csv","{\"identified\":true,\"analyzed\":true}",33999,"KgSBFstbdthdsssssstvbA==","2022-01-02 13:07:23"),
```

In this answer I don't use the `'\''` but the hexadecimal notation `\x27`.
First "backup" the `\'` combinations (replace them by an unused character like `\r`), replace all normal quotes by double quotes and "restore the backup" (change back the `\r`).

```
sed 's/\\\x27/\r/g; s/\x27/"/g; s/\r/\\\x27/g' test.sql
# or hex value for double quote "
sed 's/\\\x27/\r/g; s/\x27/\x22/g; s/\r/\\\x27/g' test.sql
```